# Rancher ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, rancher

[image]

[image]

[image]

I installed rancher on ubuntu 20.04 on vm (gcp)

I'm getting connection refused error

any help ?

( I'm not devops not trying to improve myself also I keep go on React Native )

This university homework anyone can help ?

Comment: 1) More details are required on what you configured. 2) What command is returning connection refused? Where are you executing the command? 3) Did you try `docker run --privileged ....`? Before posting a question, research the error message and show what you tried to solve that error. 4) Also, do not post images for text messages. Copy and paste the text into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rancher Official docs](https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/getting-started/installation-and-upgrade/other-installation-methods/rancher-on-a-single-node-with-docker)

I solved. because of the port

rancher work only at 443 port

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes, a "connection refused" error indicates that a network connection to a specific service or endpoint was attempted, but the target host declined the connection request. This issue may originate from a variety of sources within the Kubernetes cluster or the underlying infrastructure.

You can refer to the public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#connection_refused) regarding the 'connection refused' error for further checking.